# Create access token and refresh token from oauth2 playground

Tags: oauth2-playground

I need to get access token and refresh token from google's oauth2 playground but I don't know for sure which scopes should I use in order to get the right token for Google Analytics 4

Please help me solve this out.

Thank you so much.
[Google Developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A7hd.png)